# Why is this boost::variant missing operator<<?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

I've read that a `boost::variant` is streamable if all of its variants are streamable. However,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<int>& v) {
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        out << " " << v[i];
    return out;
}

int main() {
    boost::variant<int, std::string > a(3);
    std::cout << a << '\n'; // OK

    std::vector<int> b(3, 1);
    std::cout << b << '\n'; // OK

    boost::variant<int, std::vector<int> > c(3);
    std::cout << c << '\n'; // ERROR
}
```

fails to compile. Why?

Versions:

- Boost 1.53
- GCC 4.6.3

Comment: DONT make us GUESS. Post the error ALSO!...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't checked the documentation of serialization, but I'm pretty sure that `operator<<` for the types of `boost::variant` needs to be either found by Argument Dependent Lookup or else be present in `boost` namespace.

[This works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/994ef539cb712be6):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <boost/serialization/variant.hpp>

namespace boost {

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<int>& v) {
        for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
            out << " " << v[i];
        return out;
    }

}

int main() {
    boost::variant<int, std::string > a(3);
    std::cout << a << '\n';

    {
    using namespace boost;
    std::vector<int> b(3, 1);
    std::cout << b << '\n';
    }

    boost::variant<int, std::vector<int> > c(3);
    std::cout << c << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
3
 1 1 1
3
```

Comment: Still confused. Why isn't my `operator<<` found via Koenig lookup? (Strictly speaking, my question was "why") Defining functions in `boost` for objects that are not from Boost seems like a bad practice.

Comment: @MaxB because argument dependent lookup looks in the related namespaces, being `::std` (from std::vector and/or std::ostream),  only